# Como usar o Oauth no arquivo application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, yaml

Eu tinha um arquivo application.yml usando o Oauth da seguinte forma:

```
oauth:
  enabled: true
  all-in-one: true
```

Mas agora preciso usar o arquivo application.properties e a estrutura é diferente. Achei que fosse fosse apenas assim:

```
  oauth.enabled= true
  oauth.all-in-one= true
```

Mas não funciona. Queria saber como deixar o que tem no arquivo application.yml na estrutura do arquivo application.properties